# Flink checkpoints fail when writing to blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job that reads from a Kafka topic (*with 6 partitions*), processes each event over a window (*currently a 24 hour window*) and then sinks the windowed events to a blob storage container.

I use the Flink FileSink in bulk mode to write a parquet file. The part files are created but are never finalized. I have set my state back-end to use RocksDB and my checkpoint file storage is another blob storage container.

The part files are created but never finalized on blob storage, even after all the messages on Kafka have been read. All the checkpoints fail.

What is the reason that it could be failing to checkpoint?

When running the job with a parallelism of 1, the Kafka messages are read, the windows are processed (*I have log entries to confirm*) and the part files are created but never finalized.

The checkpoints fail with a message that the checkpoint expired before completing.

I have tried upping the timeout (increasing to an hour), limiting concurrent checkpoints to 1 and setting the pause between checkpoints to 30 minutes (*as an example*) but nothing seems to help.

I have also tried increasing the parallelism but this doesn't help.

The job runs on one task manager and I do not see anything in the logs that could point to an error (*I have DEBUG mode enabled*).

[image: Failing checkpoints]
[image: Job overview]